# Acid catalyst decarboxylation of 1-carboxyl-tryptoline

Tags: reaction-mechanism

One of my labs had the following reaction:

[image: Reaction]

I understand the Pictet Spengler mechanism. However, I am confused about the decarboxylation. I cannot come up with a way in which this decarboxylation would be acid catalyzed. Here is what I have for the Pictet mechanism:

[image: Mechanism]

I have been trying to figure out the acid catalyzed decarboxylation for several days now but I cannot. This is the closest I can come up with, but I'm not sure that this is correct:

[image: Proposed Mechanism]

Thanks!

Comment: If you protonate the beta position of the indole, the resultant immonium salt is isoelectronic with a a beta-keto acid, which readily decarboxylate.

Answer (score 4):

Your suggested mechanism should be acceptable (need two more steps, protonation and deprotonation, see last two steps of my scheme below), if you have isolated the carboxylic acid product (compound $\bf{1}$ in my scheme). If compound $\bf{1}$ is not isolable, I suggest following path would be taken to decarboxylation:

[image: Protonation and decarboxylation]

Your reaction is an analog to Pictet Spengler reaction ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pictet%E2%80%93Spengler_reaction)). When the intermediate $\bf{I}$ is formed during the reaction as depicted in the mechanism, 1,2-hydride transfer is possible to give more stable carbocation $\bf{II}$, which is resonance stabilized $(\bf{\ce{II <-> III}})$. The intermediate $\bf{III}$ can easily undergo decarboxylation to give some what stable enamine product, $\bf{2}$. In acidic medium, this enamine $\bf{2}$ would undergo protonation to give the intermediate $\bf{IV}$, which would then deprotonated to gain aromaticity and give thermodynamically stable indole product, $\bf{3}$ (the intended product).